# d3 force layout - positioning nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently working with D3.js and it's force graph layout. I am struggling to get the nodes positioned correctly, they seem to overlap I am wanting a clear gap between each child node.

I have an example of what my current work in progress looks like with the code (pretty much directly taken from the d3 example but with a larger radius)

https://jsbin.com/pajopizawi/edit?html,output

What am I doing wrong that is making the child nodes overlap?

Comment: You could just increase the repulsive force between the nodes by increasing the *negative* charge. A value of `-600` seems to do well.

Comment: Your use of 'child nodes' makes me think perhaps the problem is you're using a force-directed graph, which has no guarantee over node overlap, when one of the d3 tree layouts would be a better choice. They're designed to give each node it's own space. If your structure is a tree try that instead.

Comment: @mrgraham I totally agree but I want to able to drag to isolate the connections and have the innertia effect.

Comment: how about  giving -ve charge and gravity something like this https://jsbin.com/dibicazewi/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late here, but isn't this what "[forceCollide](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#forceCollide)" is for. I set the radius of my nodes to 6 and forceCollide 16 seems to keep them nicely apart.

`.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(16));`

Although this is in V4, doesn't seem to work in your example.